# How to delete BIOS password?

Tags: windows-7, bios

I have a problem with my BIOS.
There is a password in my BIOS and I cannot delete it.

I tried these methods:

1) Tried to take out battery for 3 days; 
2) Tried to write debug, but my Windows 7 is 64 bit and there is no debug command
3) Tried to use standard passwords that offers internet
4) Tried to clear CMOS with cmospwd program
5) Opened case, and found CMOS_CLEAR 2 pins, but there was no jumper. Took other jumper and tried to reset, it didn't work. Maybe I did something wrong. 
My BIOS is:
 American Megatrends Inc. 
Version: BB3F1P10 
Motherboard: Foxconn H61MXE/-S/-V/-K

Comment: If you provide the vendor and model of the computer, it could be easy to help you. Some devices (HP, for example) are very difficulty and need "special" software to reset them.

Comment: Just personal computer. I have written Motherboard model.

Answer (score 1):

From your [user manual](http://www.foxconnchannel.com/driverdownload/Motherboard/Intel/Socket%201155/H61M06/Manual/H61MXE%20Series-Manual-En-V1.0-0221.pdf.zip) you can reset the cmos by shorting the jumper in the diagram below.

[Your motherboard support page](http://www.foxconnchannel.com/ProductDetail.aspx?T=motherboard&U=en-us0000567)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks too much! Today I will try this method. And will write you back.

Comment: How to put a screwdriver onto pins? I ve just put it onto and kept for a while. It didn't work. It asks again password.

Comment: Be sure power cord is removed, then hold power button in for 15 seconds, this discharges the motherboard of residual electricity, then short the pins with a small screwdriver for 15 seconds.

Comment: As far as I understand, I have to do these: 1. Remove power cord; 2. Hold power button in for 15 seconds; 3. After that, put a screwdriver onto pins and keep it for 15 seconds. Then I will try to open again PC.

Comment: It did not work. I surfed in the internet, and it is said that the password kept in EEPROM. But shortening pins didnt work. Please help me! May you take the photo how to shorten that pins?

Comment: If the password is kept in EEPROM, then resetting the bios will not reset the password, only the manufacturer can do a password reset.

Comment: Contact Foxconn to see if there is a way you can do it.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to reset the BIOS completely using jumper pins on the motherboard. Make sure your computer is disconnected from the power when doing this.

Consult your motherboard documentation for details.

See information found online:

> Clear CMOS data   is the fast way to go back to factory default when the
>   BIOS settings were mistakenly modified. The steps to clear CMOS data
>   are :
>
> 1. Turn off the computer, unplug the power    cord from the power outlet.
> 2. Remove jumper cap from pins 1-2, put it onto pins 2-3 to short them.
>      This will clear CMOS data.
> 3. Return the setting to its original with pins 1-2 closed. Plug in the power cord to your computer and turn it on.
> 4. Go to BIOS Setup to configure new system

Comment: The author already tried this per the information in the question.

Comment: Yes, but possibly with the wrong jumper or power plugged in. This is the method for reset for this particular motherboard.

Comment: please help me guys

Comment: @ITEngineer - We can't.  You are asking for the impossible.